# Как правильно хранить файлы на веб-сервере?

Tags: php, файлы, хранение-данных

Я бы хотел задать кое-какие вопросы о построении каталогов и хранении в них файлов (картинок, к примеру).

Прежде чем обратиться, я почитал не мало разных статей и у меня накопились вопросы.

Ни для кого не секрет, что для крупных проектов нецелесообразно скидывать загружаемые пользователем файлы в одну папку и поэтому нужно раскидывать их по каталогам, но как сделать это правильно?

Многие советуют делать это след. образом:
Вкратце опишу, генерируем название файла с помощью `md5` хэша.
Затем, берем первые 2 символа из название и создаём папку и туда помещаем все файлы, которые начинаются на одни и те же символы, подобным образом мы можем создать 256 папок в которые, к примеру, мы можем поместить по 1000 файлов. Разумеется, можно делать вложенные уровни из 3 и 4 символа из 5 и 6 и тд.

Но я не могу понять, что будет, если одна из папок забьется гораздо раньше чем другие? Как в таком случае быть?

Мой вариант, который пришел в голову (Думаю, я не первый):
Создаем папку с числом текущего года, к примеру, затем текущего месяца и в папке с числом месяца создаем папку с днем месяца и в ней создаем папку с названием 1 и забиваем её до тех пор пока в ней не будет 1000 файлов, затем создаем папку с числом 2 и забиваем её, ну и в таком же духе и дальше.

Выходит, если мы будет хранить в папке до тысячи папок и в этих папках до тысячи файлов, то у нас в одной папке которая названа числом месяца может храниться до 30 000 000 файлов. После того как месяц закончился переходим к другому, закончился год, переходит к другому...
Файловой системе в таком случае не придется тонны файлов разгребать, максимальное число файлов с которыми придется ей работать это 1000

Для наглядности:
2015/04/15/1

Забиваем папку с названием 1 до 1000 файлов, затем создаем папку с названием 2, после 3 и так до 1000

Закончился день, тогда создаем в папке 04 папку 16 и дальше по описанному принципу работаем.
Разумеется, папки создаются только тогда, когда в них грузятся файлы.

Какие у вас мысли по этому поводу? Какую структуру хранения файлов используете вы? И чем она хороша? Приемлема ли та структура которую описал я, с вашей точки зрения? Что скажете по поводу производительности?

Comment: Вообще папки придумали для человека, чтобы он мог группировать файлы и структурировать их. Файловой системе глубоко чихать на то как там файлы хранятся. Они просто размазаны по всему дисковому пространству. В текущих реалиях скорость доступа (чтение, запись) к данным это характеристика устройства хранения.

Comment: Ну вот я это и имею ввиду. Как лучше хранить файлы, чтобы ФС было проще их читать, записывать, удалять?

Comment: Еще раз повторяюсь - ФС все равно. Понятие *папка* абстрактное. Если хотите скорости, то платите деньги за SSD хостинг

Comment: А почему тогда скорость чтения из директории где 1000 файлов гораздо быстрее, нежели чтения из директории где файлов 50 000?

Comment: Ну а вы попробуйте прочитать список файлов из 50 папок по 1000 файлов, и потом папку в 50000. Будет разница в 50 раз?

Comment: Я понимаю что вы имеете ввиду, но, представим, что имеется веб страница на которой нужно вывести 50 фотографий (полные адреса с путями хранятся в БД), так вот, если каждую фотографию читать из одной папке, то это будет гораздо дольше, нежели обращаться к папкам где по 1000 фотографий. Понимаете к чему я клоню? Так же само и другие операции: удаление, перемещение.... В случае с папкой в которой 50 тыс. фотографий, нужно будет обращаться к этой папке 50 раз и искать в этом скопе одну картинку

Comment: В целом, подход с md5-хэшем вполне жизнеспособный. Если одна из папок забьется раньше других ничего ужасного не случится. А хэш-функция как раз и заботится о более-менне равномерном заполнении папок.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! Я когда ближе к этой проблеме подойду, буду уже выбирать правильный подход, нужно будет тщательно взвесить все.

Comment: > Но я не могу понять, что будет, если одна из папок забьется гораздо раньше чем другие? Как в таком случае быть?

Comment: Нужно исходить из типа файловой системы, задач, количества и размера файлов, характера нагрузки.

Comment: Файлов система ext3 или ext4. Кстати, вы верно подметили. Очень важный вопрос. Насколько важен размер файла? И почему он важен? К пример, у меня 2 директории в которых по 5 000 файлов, в одной файлы по 500 кб., а в другой по 50 мб. поиск файлов (именно поиск, а не чтение) будет одинаковым?

Comment: Нагрузка будет такая: чтение, удаление, перемещение (редко)

Comment: К вашей структуре каталогов (год/месяц/день/...) понадобиться еще и файл-индекс (а скорее структура из несколько таких  файлов) для поиска файла по имени. Иначе, для того чтобы убедиться, что запрашиваемого файла в системе нет придется просмотреть содержимое всего дерева каталогов. / По поводу последнего вопроса (в комментарии) -- время поиска файла в каталоге от размера файла не зависит.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ достаточно общий, без всякой привязки к PHP.

Если требуется поиск файлов по имени, то я бы попробовал все же сделать структуру, основанную на MD5 (или другой хэш-функции) в 16-ричном виде (для MD5 все имя это 32 символа от 0 до f), только не с жесткой организацией уровней каталогов, а с динамической.

Имена каталогов задаются, например,  тройками символов. Соответственно, каталог может содержать до 4096 других каталогов.

Для начала начинаем помещать в каталог сами файлы (с MD5-именем). Можно еще завести там служебный файл для отображения хэша в имя (может пригодиться, если захотите узнать реальные имена хранимых файлов) и синонимов (вдруг такое произойдет). Впрочем, структура такого файла -- это отдельный вопрос.

Когда в каталоге соберется 4096 файлов мы проводим реорганизацию. Делаем по первой тройке символов имен файлов каталоги и перемещаем файлы в них.

Надеюсь, далее очевидно.

Answer (score 2):

> что будет, если одна из папок забьется гораздо раньше чем другие?

Странный вопрос. С какой стати одна должна забиться раньше? Это ведь рандомный хэш, а не пользовательское имя файла на IMG_. Ну да, хэш надо генерировать с умом. Но это проблема генерации хэша, а не самого принципа. То есть я не понимаю логику, стоящую за этим доводом. Это все равно что решать, чем есть борщ, и отказаться от ложки только потому, что кто-то, возможно, её в руках не умеет держать. Ну так надо одного криворукого учить, а не всем хлебать через край.

Чем система проще, тем она лучше работает.
В простой системе нечему ломаться.

Если изначально задать алгоритм, который не будет требовать никаких пересчетов и реорганизаций, то он и будет работать без необходимости каждый раз(!) файлы в папке пересчитывать.

Самый оптимальный вариант - это md5() от содержимого. Обеспечит не только
вполне случайное распределение, но и сэкономит место в случае дублей (только при удалении надо быть внимательным и смотреть нет ли других записей, ссылающихся на тот же файл).

Плюс можно перевести хэш из 16-ричной системы в 36-ричную, задействовав все буквы алфавита, а не только первые 6. Что сократит длину хэша и одновременно увеличит количество вариантов для разбивки, уменьшая необходимую глубину папок.

Comment: Ну, глубина-то (от перехода к 36 или 64-ричной) не уменьшиться (если мы хотим ограничить количество файлов в каждом каталоге).

Comment: Ооо, лайк за 36, тоже ее использую)

Answer (score 1):

Поделюсь своими наработками
Функция генерирует путь, проверяет его существование и создаёт вложенные папки в директории $link.
Может также использоваться для генерации случайной строки если передать $path=false.

```
function gen_indire($nestinglevel,$path=true,$link=false){

    if ($path){$nestinglevel = $nestinglevel*2;}

    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    //Для UNIX систем можно добавить заглавные буквы
    $patch = ""; 
    $clen = strlen($chars) - 1;
    while (strlen($patch) < $nestinglevel) { 
        if ($path){$patch .= $chars[mt_rand(0,$clen)] . "/";}
        else{$patch .= $chars[mt_rand(0,$clen)];}
    }
    if ($link){
        if (!file_exists($link.$patch)){
            mkdir ($link.$patch,0777,true);
        }
    }
    return $patch;
}

//генерируем путь в заданной папке и создаём его, если его ещё нет 
$prefix=gen_indire(5,true,"/home/storage/");
//получаем в ответ что-то вроде a/1/c/2/e/

//генерируем имя файла 
$filename=gen_indire(10,false)."-".time();
// uioe2bdocu9-123456789123

//если планируется прямой доступ к файлу, добавляем оригинальное расширение 
$filename.=pathinfo($_FILES['upload']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//Сохраняем $prefix и $filename в базу желательно в отдельные столбцы,
//чтобы запись в базе, при необходимости, можно было найти по имени файла.
```

Answer (score 0):

Однажды я делал фотохостинг, и я делал следующим образом:
По задумке сайта, для каждой картинки есть ссылка в формате `example.com/vnjum`. Как в сокращалке ссылок.
Тогда картинка сохраняется в папку `example.com/images/v/n/j/u/m/image.jpg`
Тогда и из ссылки на сайт можно получить ссылку на сам файл и наоборот)

---

Вот вам еще один метод. 
В документа будет два идентификатора - время загрузки и случайное число от 100 000 до 999 999.

Для примера, время будет `1540670259710` (это UNIX-формат), а случайное число - `125793`.

Переводим дату в 36-ричную систему (в JavaScript - `.toString(36)`), получаем `jnrvakn2`. Делим на куски по 1-2-2-3 символа. Получаем `j`-`nr`-`va`-`kn2`.

Далее берем наше случайное число - `125793`. В 36-ричной системе это будет `2p29`.

Получаем адрес `/j/nr/va/kn2/2p29/filename.jpg`